# python bokeh deselect data table rows

Tags: python, select, datatable, bokeh

I want to be able to "reset" a [data table](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/widgets.tables.html#bokeh.models.widgets.tables.DataTable). How do I do that?

I have a defined an `on_change('selected', my_callback)` callback for my data table. The callback function has the following signature:

```
def my_callback(self, attr, old, new):
    ...
```

However I'm not able to deselect what has been selected after the `my_callback` handler is called.

I have tried to manipulate the `new['1d']` or `old['1d']` dictionaries without success.

What is the proper way to deselect rows in a data table and go back to the original state where nothing was selected?

There's a [similar question](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/U3kCtp3QPTM) on G-groups but it had no answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bokeh application example. I do not know what you are trying to do as you have not posted your code exactly. The key to deselecting or changing the selected data from a source is you need to replace the entire object or a change will not be registered. The exact same functionality could be achieved through javascript callbacks.

See a related example here, [Bokeh: DataTable - how to set selected rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594434/bokeh-datatable-how-to-set-selected-rows/45329009#45329009)

```
from datetime import date
from random import randint
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn, Button

output_file("data_table.html")

data = dict(
        dates=[date(2014, 3, i+1) for i in range(10)],
        downloads=[randint(0, 100) for i in range(10)],
    )
source = ColumnDataSource(data)

columns = [
        TableColumn(field="dates", title="Date", formatter=DateFormatter()),
        TableColumn(field="downloads", title="Downloads"),
    ]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=400, height=280)

def callback():
    source.selected = {'0d': {'glyph': None, 'indices': []},
                       '1d': {'indices': []},
                       '2d': {'indices': {}}}

button = Button(label="Reset all selected cells", button_type="success")
button.on_click(callback)

curdoc().add_root(widgetbox(data_table,button))
```

Answer (score 2):

To deselect `DataTable` rows programmatically and go back to the original state where nothing was selected, you may use this in python:

```
source.selected.indices = []
```

where `source` is the `ColumnDataSource` for the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason source.selected.indices = [] did not work for my DataTable, it worked for clicking on squares on a map though.

source.selected.indices[0]=1000 worked for both
(1000 should be any number that is larger than the no. of rows in the datatable, so that it can't occur by clicking)

Code I used was:

```
def bokeh_changeTabOnClick(source,tabs):
    myCallback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, tabs=tabs), code="""
        // get the selected row's index
        var row_index = source.selected.indices[0];
        tabs.active = row_index + 1;
        // Clear the selected indices (otherwise can't click same row/ map square again)
        // source.selected.indices = [];     /* this didn't work with my DataTable for some reason perhaps someone else can explain why
        source.selected.indices[0] = 1000;   /* reset to something that will never occur by clicking so that if row is clicked on it will be a change */  
        """)
    # attach the callback to the source.selected property
    source.selected.js_on_change('indices', myCallback)
        
    return 0
```